# How to install HDBODBC Drivers in a Linux Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, odbc, hana, unixodbc

I am trying to connect to a SAP HANA database from a Linux Dockerfile. Currently having trouble with installing the HDBODBC Driver in the Dockerfile or finding resources for it.

1. How can I install HDBODBC Driver in a Dockerfile?
2. Do I need an odbc.ini file or is using a connection string sufficient?

Note: I am familiar with connecting to SAP HANA without docker and on Windows using a connection string

Dockerfile currently:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16.13.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get install odbcinst

COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

When I run my code with just the connection string I am seeing:

```
[Error: [odbc] Error connecting to the database] {
   odbcErrors: [
     {
       state: '01000',
       code: 0,
       message: "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'HDBODBC' : file not found"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Which makes me think I don't have the driver installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the HANA Client.  Try here: https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).